# Load table with updated data via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile app using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. Basically for the first time when the app loads the data which gets populated using AJAX comes fine but It doesn't update.

Example: If there are 5 rows of data coming from the database and with some users action 1 more row has been added in the database but it still displays 5 rows. Currently it updates only if I exit app fully.

Also to solve this problem I have tried the following:

**tbody.append(tableCells).load();**

**tbody.append(tableCells).trigger('create');**

**tbody.append(tableCells).trigger('refresh');**

Any solution/idea how can I update it live or something without a user exits the app completely? Please see the below code.

**Code:**

HTML:

```
<table id="myPendingChallenges-table" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Game Type</th>
       <th>Team Name</th>
       <th>Initiator Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

to append rows inside the

JS: **tbody.append(tableCells);**

AJAX:

```
var currentUser = window.localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
user = JSON.parse(currentUser);
var username = user.username; //User name

//alert (username+', '+t_name+', '+formAction);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/webservice/index.php',
    data: {username: username},
    dataType : 'json',      
    success: function(data){
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        window.localStorage.setItem("teamChallenges", json);
        challengePopulate();
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error!');
    }
});
 return false;

function challengePopulate()
{
    var json = window.localStorage.getItem("teamChallenges");
    var data = null;
    if(!json)
        data = JSON.stringify(window.teamChallenges);
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    if(!data)
        return;
    var fields = ["game_type", "t_name", "ini_name"];
populatePCTable("#myPendingChallenges-table", fields, data);
}//end challengePopulate


function populatePCDTable(tableId, fields, data) 
{
    var tbody = $(tableId + " tbody");
    var row = null;
    for(var i in data) {
        row = data[i];  

        if(!row)
            continue;

        var tableCells = "";
        var fieldName = "";

        for(var j in fields){
            fieldName = fields[j];
            teamName = row[fields[1]];
            gameParam = row[fields[3]];

            if(row[fieldName] == 'weighin'){
                game_type = 'weighin';
                row[fieldName] = '<img src="images/weightGame.png" width="100%" />';    
            }else if (row[fieldName] == 'activity'){
                game_type = 'activity';
                row[fieldName] = '<img src="images/activityGame.png" width="100%" />';  
            }

            tableCells += "<td onClick=\"setPendingChallTitle('"+teamName+"');pendingchallengeDetails('"+teamName+"');\"><a href='#pendingChallengesDetailsPage'>"+row[fieldName]+"</a></td>";
        }
        tbody.append("<tr>" + tableCells + "<td onClick=\"ignorePendingChallenge(this,'"+teamName+"');\"><a href=''><img src='images/close_button.png' title='Ignore Challenge' /></a></td></tr>"); 
    }
}//end function populatePCDTable
```

Comment: i think we need to see what challengePopulate does

Comment: @drakoumelitos please check the update I have made above. It's with all the possible code

Comment: you dont get any errors on the console right? cant think of anything other than syntax errors try organizing it a bit better, cant find anything wrong tho. 

$("#tableID").find('tbody')
    .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
            .append($('<img>')
                .attr('src', 'img.png')
                .text('Image cell')
            )
        )
    );

Comment: PopulatePCDTable looks OK except this line: gameParam = row[fields[3]]; because fields does not have a 4rth entry.  What does the JSON data look like, it should be something like this:[{"game_type": "game_type1", "t_name":"t_name1", "ini_name":"ini_name1"},
               {"game_type": "game_type2", "t_name":"t_name2", "ini_name":"ini_name2"},
               {"game_type": "game_type3", "t_name":"t_name3", "ini_name":"ini_name3"}];